# CLion changes Project Folders after loading CMake.txt

Tags: cmake, clion, zephyr-rtos

I want to develop an application with Zephyr RTOS in CLion. For that I opened the Hello World sample. Then I configured in the CLion Settings CMake: [CMake Settings in CLion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C59oa.png) but after pressing apply my Project Folders change from: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC6Ig.png) to [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ymXg.png)

My CMake.txt:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

# Set the target board
set(BOARD nucleo_f103rb)

# Set the toolchain
#set(ZEPHYR_TOOLCHAIN_VARIANT zephyr)
#set(GNUARMEMB_TOOLCHAIN_PATH "C:/Users/Chris/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi")

# Add source files
FILE(GLOB app_sources src/*.c)

find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(hello_world)

target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
```

Can anyone help. Thanks a lot.

I tried the gnuarmembed toolchain instead of the Zepyr one but got the same result.